# Maximize View.OnTouchListener sample rate?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touchscreen

When a View.OnTouchListener() is receiving MotionEvents (including historical ones that occurred since the last call to onTouch()), does Android (13) capture samples at the highest rate the phone's hardware is capable of, or does it *normally* limit the sample rate, and only kick it up to max if you somehow explicitly *ask* it to (kind of like a gaming mouse that's *capable* of delivering 1000hz+ sample rates when requested, but normally limits itself to 125 or 250hz under Windows to improve battery life).

Along a similar line... is View.OnTouchListener() the way to get touchscreen samples at the absolute maximum rate the hardware allows, or is there some new/alternate API (probably intended for gaming) that exposes higher sample rates than the phone would normally be inclined to use?

If there **is** a way (available as of Android 13 on a Pixel 7 Pro) to sample the touchscreen at a faster rate than View.OnTouchListener() normally allows/defaults-to, what is it?

Note that I'm *not* asking, "How can I make onTouch() get called more frequently". The current *reporting rate* and historical batching is fine. I just want the sample-to-sample time *of* those batches to be as low as the hardware & Android conceivably allows.

Answer (score 0):

Android 13 does not have a way to explicitly set the touch sampling rate of the touchscreen. The touch sampling rate depends on the hardware and the firmware of the device. I.e.: A Pixel 7 Pro has a touch sampling rate of 240 Hz, which means it can register touches every 4.167 milliseconds.

As for the alternative to `View.OnTouchListener()`, there are some options you can try:

- Use `View.onTouchEvent()` instead, which is the original method that `View.OnTouchListener()` overrides.
- Use `GestureDetector` in combination with `View.OnTouchListener()`, which can detect clicks and other touch events.
- You can also try a lib that might offer more control over the touch input, such as LibGDX or Unity.

Maximize View.OnTouchListener sample rate? [Maximize View.OnTouchListener sample rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410557/maximize-view-ontouchlistener-sample-rate).

4 Ways to Check Touch Sampling Rate (Response Rate) https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/08/03/check-touch-sampling-rate-response-rate-display-android/.

The importance of touch-to-display response time in gaming. https://www.dxomark.com/the-importance-of-touch-to-display-response-time-in-gaming/.

View.OnTouchListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the maximum sample rate for touchscreen input, you may
set `MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED` (before API 31 it was `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED`) and `MotionEvent.FLAG_SPLIT` event flags for the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` event. In particular, by activating the  event flags, you can enhance the device's capability to capture samples at a more frequent interval.

1. `MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED` allows the device to obtain `MotionEvent` data when a touched view is obstructed by another view. This feature can prove helpful in scenarios where an application or game exhibits several views overlaying on the screen, and it's necessary to collect input data from all views.
2. `MotionEvent.FLAG_SPLIT` flag permits the device to record MotionEvent data from numerous points of contact concurrently. This functionality comes in handy when the user interacts with the screen using multiple fingers, such as in games that necessitate multitouch input.